# creating new columns in a data set based on values of a column using Regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

This is my data frame

```
index     duration 
1           7 year   
2           2day
3           4 week
4           8 month
```

I need to separate numbers from time and put them in two new columns. The output is like this:

```
index     duration         number     time
1           7 year          7         year
2           2day            2         day
3           4 week          4        week
4           8 month         8         month
```

This is my code:

```
df ['numer'] = df.duration.replace(r'\d.*' , r'\d', regex=True, inplace = True)
df [ 'time']= df.duration.replace (r'\.w.+',r'\w.+', regex=True, inplace = True )
```

But it does not work. Any suggestion ?

I also need to create another column based on the values of time column. So the new dataset is like this:

```
 index     duration         number     time      time_days
    1           7 year          7         year       365
    2           2day            2         day         1
    3           4 week          4        week         7
    4           8 month         8         month       30

df['time_day']= df.time.replace(r'(year|month|week|day)', r'(365|30|7|1)', regex=True, inplace=True)
```

Any suggestion ?

Comment: what is your end goal? how are you going to use those parsed columns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

we can use [Series.str.extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) here:

```
In [67]: df[['number','time']] = df.duration.str.extract(r'(\d+)\s*(.*)', expand=True)

In [68]: df
Out[68]:
   index duration number    time
0      1   7 year      7    year
1      2     2day      2     day
2      3   4 week      4    week
3      4  8 month      8   month
```

[RegEx explained](https://regex101.com/r/iZfjMo/1) - regex101.com is IMO one of the best online RegEx parser, tester and explainer

you may also want to convert `number` column to integer dtype:

```
In [69]: df['number'] = df['number'].astype(int)

In [70]: df.dtypes
Out[70]:
index        int64
duration    object
number       int32
time        object
dtype: object
```

**UPDATE:**

```
In [167]: df['time_day'] = df['time'].replace(['year','month','week','day'], [365, 30, 7, 1], regex=True)

In [168]: df
Out[168]:
   index duration number    time  time_day
0      1   7 year      7    year       365
1      2     2day      2     day         1
2      3   4 week      4    week         7
3      4  8 month      8   month        30
```

Comment: would you please explain how this code df.duration.str.extract(r'(\d+)\s*?(.*)$', expand=True) works? I do not understand the ? and $ here .

Comment: @Mary, i've slightly optimized the RegEx and have added a link to the explained RegEx - please check

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df = df['duration'].str.extract(r'(?P<number>\d+)\s*(?P<time>\w+)', expand=True)
#convert to int
df['number'] = df['number'].astype(int)
print (df)
   number   time
0       7   year
1       2    day
2       4   week
3       8  month
```

[Extracting substrings](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#extracting-substrings).

For adding to original `DataFrame`:

```
df = df.join(df['duration'].str.extract(r'(?P<number>\d+)\s*(?P<time>\w+)', expand=True))
#convert to int
df['number'] = df['number'].astype(int)
print (df)
   index duration  number   time
0      1   7 year       7   year
1      2     2day       2    day
2      3   4 week       4   week
3      4  8 month       8  month
```

---

```
df[['number','time']] = df['duration'].str.extract(r'(\d+)\s*(\w+)', expand=True)
#convert to int
df['number'] = df['number'].astype(int)
print (df)
   index duration  number   time
0      1   7 year       7   year
1      2     2day       2    day
2      3   4 week       4   week
3      4  8 month       8  month
```

Comment: Sorry, now Iam on phone only. So I prefer map by dict.  `d = {'year':365, 'month':30, 'week':7, 'day':1}
 df['time_day'] = df['time'].map(d)`. It works perfect if only 4 possible values in column `time`, else get NaNs. replace is used if need change not all values, but only some. So here is better map. But if in columns are values  `a, b, c,d, e,f... ` and need change only `a,c` to `b,d` better solution is replace. Good luck!